# Codeigniter - Routing with Query strings

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am a novice at Codeigniter. I have developed a simple search form and on clicking it the results are displayed.

I have used get method in my form due to which when I search, the URL is like domain/Search/search_func?keyword=test&submit=Search. I want to change the URL to something like domain/Search/test. 
Here Search is my controller and search_func is my method and test is the get parameter.
I have tried using 
`$route['Search/search_func?(:any)'] = 'Search/search_func';' 
but no luck..
Can anyone help on this?

### HTML

```
<form name="search_form" action="/Search/search_func">
Search: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords, city, country, etc." name="keyword">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
```

### CONTROLLER

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('search');
    }
    public function search_func()
    {
        $this->load->model('Search_model');
        $result['rows'] = $this->Search_model->search_result();
        $this->load->view('search_results',$result);
    }
}
?>
```

### MODEL

```
 <?php

class Search_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function search_result(){
        $this->load->database();
        $keyword  = $this->input->get('keyword'); 
        //$query = $this->db->get("employee");
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from employee where city like '%".$keyword."%' or state like'%".$keyword."%' or country like '%".$keyword."%'");
        $results = $query->result();
        return $results;
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="search_form" action="/search/">
Search: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter keywords, city, country, etc." name="keyword">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">

$route['Search/(:any)'] = 'Search/search_func/$1';
```

here search is your controller (:any) will be mapped to your get parameter and will be processed by search_func of search Controller.

Comment: It dint work.. On clicking the search button directly the URL becomes domain/Search/search_func?keyword=test&submit=Search.

Comment: @Diana Url is not build by routes ,so you have to create url.

Comment: Do you mean by .htaccess ?

Comment: how do you search with ajax or form submit ?

Comment: With form submit.. Get Parameter

Comment: then url in form action ="search/"

Comment: Please refer the form code which i have used in my question.. Let me know what should I change there.

Answer (score 0):

Your route have set

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/search_func/$1';
```

Your controller must have a parameter.
So your controller function

```
public function search_func($keyword)
{
$this->load->model('Search_model');
        $result['rows'] = $this->Search_model->search_result($keyword);
        $this->load->view('search_results',$result);
}
```

On your model function

```
public function search_result($keyword){
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query("select * from employee where city like '%".$keyword."%' or state like'%".$keyword."%' or country like '%".$keyword."%'");
        $results = $query->result();
        return $results;
    }
```